# Is there a way to show the progress of a function in another class?

Tags: java, progress-bar, swt

I am having trouble with the making of a progressbar. I want the bar to show how far the function 'GiveRating' is with it's progress. It doesn't have to be very precise. I am new to Java so please explain in simple words. I am using Java SWT for the GUI

```
// this is the new progress bar which is showing in a shell:

ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shlRatingScheme, SWT.NONE); 
progressBar.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
progressBar.setBounds(10, 208, 170, 17);


// this is the button that's starts the process:

btnFotosRaten.setText("Foto's raten");
btnFotosRaten.setBounds(185, 270, 75, 25);
btnFotosRaten.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
public void handleEvent(Event e) {switch (e.type) {case SWT.Selection:
PhotoRating d = new PhotoRating();
if(sFolder == null | dFolder == null) {
String message ="Vul bronmap en doelmap in AUB!";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "Oeps", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}else {
d.GiveRating(dFolder);

// so I would like to let the progress bar show how far d.GiveRating(dfolder) is. Is there a simple way to do that?

}
String message ="De foto's in "+dFolder+" zijn gerated!"; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
break;
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "watch" a function as it runs. what you can do is make the function inform something of what it does.

You can implement something called "observer pattern" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern ). In your case you will need an intermediate class that will observe the function running and for every event it will update your progress bar.

something like

```java
public class ProgressBarObserver implements Observer{
 ProgressBar pb;

 public ProgressBarObserver(ProgressBar pb){
   this.pb = pb;
 }

 @Override
 public void update(int progress){
  pb.step(progress); // cannot recall the correct function for progressbar
 }
}

public class Worker implements Observable{
 Observer o;
 public Worker(Observer o){
   this.o = o;
 }

 public void doSomething(){
 //something
 o.update(1);
 //something else
 o.update(1);
 //some other stuff
 o.update(1);
 //and so on
 }
}

public class Manager {
 public static void main(String... args){
 ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
 ProgressBarObserver pbo = new ProgressBarObserver(pb);
 Worker w = new Worker(pbo);

 w.doSomething();
 }
}
```

Hope it helped!